# "initial values are not feasible" error message while running structural equation model in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am working on a structural equation model (sem) model with 47 observed variables and 6 latent variables, of which 5 observed variables are endogenous and one latent variable is endogenous. Data has no missing values and sample size is 4,634.

I ran `sem` in Stata using the following command:

```
sem (I   -> i1 i2 i3 i4 i5_1)                                  ///
    (N   -> n1 n2 n3 n4)                                       ///
    (S   -> s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8 s9)                        ///
    (T   -> t1 t2 t3 t4)                                       ///
    (SES -> se1 se2 se3 se4 se5 se6 se7 se8 se9 se10           ///
            se11 se12 se13 se14 se15 se16 se17 se18 se19 se20) ///
    (CS  -> c1 c2 c3 c4 c5)                                    ///
    (CS  <- I N S T SES)
```

It returned the following error message:

```
initial values are not feasible
```

Why am I receiving this message? How can I deal with this error?

Comment: [this](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-05/msg00650.html) might help you

Comment: I have 5 indicators of depnedent variable how can i regress?

Comment: That error message can mean many things, to pin it down we need to see the _exact_ `sem` command you typed.

Comment: sem (I -> i1 i2 i3 i4 i5_1) (N -> n1 n2 n3 n4) (S -> s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8 s9) ( T -> t1 t2 t3 t4) (SES -> se1 se2 se3 se4 se5 se6 se7 se8 se9 se10 se11 se12 se13 se14 se15 se16 se17 se18 se19 se20) (CS-> c1 c2 c3 c4 c5) (CS <- I N S T SES)

Comment: Measurement:  i1 i2 i3 i4 i5_1 n1 n2 n3 n4 s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 t1 t2 t3 t4 se1 se2 se3 se4 se5 se6 se7 se8 se9 se10 se11 se12 se13
              se14 se15 se16 se17 se18 se19 se20 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
Latent:       CS

Exogenous variables

Latent:       I N S T SES

Fitting target model:

initial values not feasible
r(1400);

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at each measurement model separately, and see if there are problems there. i.e.:

```
sem ( i1 i2 i3 i4 i5_1 <- I)

sem ( i1 i2 i3 i4 i5_1 <- N)
```

etc.

My guess would be that the model for SES might prove to be the problem.

---

**Edit:**

Based on your comment we now know that the measurement models in isolation converge. Next step would be to check each of the measurement models to see whether they make sense: Do each of the loading have the expected sign? Are there loading that are unexpectedly large or small? If you see that, you need to figure out why that is the case. This just requires staring at your data, looking at graphs and correlation tables.

If there is no problem with your measurement model, then the next step would be to look at the structural part. Obviously you cannot do the same trick as with the measurement model, that is, you cannot estimate the structural part without the measurement models. The structural contains latent variables, and it is the measurement models that define what they are. So without measurement models, the structural model is not identified.

What I would do instead is simplify your model, and than add complication till you run into problems. For example I might start with:

```
sem (I  -> i1 i2 i3 i4 i5_1) ///
    (CS -> c1 c2 c3 c4 c5)   ///
    (CS <- I)
```

Than continue with:

```
sem (I  -> i1 i2 i3 i4 i5_1) ///
    (N  -> n1 n2 n3 n4)      ///
    (CS -> c1 c2 c3 c4 c5)   ///
    (CS <- I N)
```

etc.

That way you can find which latent variable causes trouble. My first move would be to look at the measurement model of that variable and look at the scale of that variable. By default `sem` "borrows" the scale of one of the observed variables by setting the loading for that variable to 1. Is that variable in some sense "weird"? Similarly I would also look at the scale for your endogenous latent variable `CS`. If they are weird, you can choose to constrain the loading of another variable with a more reasonable scale to 1, or you can "standardize" your latent variable by constraining the variance of the latent variable to be 1.

Comment: I have checked this way each measurment seperatly gives no error but the final structural equation follows error message 
sem (C <- I N S T SES) 
model not identified; 
no paths from latent variable C to observed variables –

Comment: please somebody guide me where the problem lies and how can I rectify?

Comment: I interpret your question as you tried to expand my advise of looking at each measurement model separately to looking at the structural part of the model separately, any you tried `sem(C <- I N S T SES)` without any of the measurement models. If that is true, than Stata is correct in telling you that that model cannot be estimated.